# How parametrize annotation?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

With java I can write something like that

```
public <T extends Enum> getValue (Class<T> clazz) {}
```

Is there a way to parametrize not from Enum, but from Annotation? So example I want write something like this:

```
public <T extends @interface> getValue (Class<T> clazz) {}
```

My goal is to be insure **during compilation time** that `clazz` variable is annotation. Any ideas? (except call `class.isAnnotation` inside a method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all annotation types are subclasses of [`java.lang.annotation.Annotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html).

> The common interface extended by all annotation types.

Use

```
public <T extends Annotation>  void /* or whatever */ getValue (Class<T> clazz) {}
```

Comment: Works. I have mistake in type parameters. :-)